# BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED for third party apps

Tags: bluetooth, pairing

BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED  permission is not available to third party apps, which is required for setPairingConfirmation() method call. Is there any other way to enable BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED for third party apps?

Comment: Got the same problem. I think this is an Android bug. What should happen is that Android is supposed to popup a dialog when a third party app tries to connect to a BTLE device and the device sends a security request. However, sometimes it doesn't so when a BroadcastReiver traps the pairing request and the application does it (because Android didnt) the error arises. IN pre-6.0 it didnt matter.